# laravel Local scope with many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get unseen places by local scope

`Place` model has a many to many relation with `User` model called `seen()`

```
public function seen()
{
    $user = $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'place_seen');

    return $user;
}
```

I want to get unseen places with local scope ,something like this :

```
/**
 * returns Unseen Places
 */
public function scopeUnSeen($query)
{
    return $query->where(????);
}
```

Comment: did you mean [`scopeUnSeen`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes)? Laravel require local scopes to be prefixed with `scope`, [read on the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L1461) it states that local scopes always prefixed with `scope` and whatever follows it will be it's method name - [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php).

Comment: @BagusTesa yeah I changed it

Comment: well then, you wish a scope for the `seen()` relation to retrieve all unseen places by user? or something else..? care to elaborate..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`doesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) function as:

```
public function scopeUnSeen($query)
{
    return $query->doesntHave('seen');
}
```